# How to write test case for this void method for if condition

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

```
public void setRefundIdForPrepaid(RefundReturnRequest refundReturnRequest) { 
    if(StringUtils.isBlank (refundReturnRequest.getRefundRequest().getRefundId())) {
        refundReturnRequest.getRefundRequest().setRefundId (Integer.toString(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(999999999)));
    }
}
```

Comment: You can edit your question to correct it.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  Show what you have tried

Comment: I have to write test case for this method please someone help me to write test case for it how to write test case for this void method

Comment: What does your test look like so far?

Comment: I have no idea how to write mockito test case for it in if condition it is checking RefundId if RefundId is null it is setting a random value in RefundId

Comment: There are debates around testing void methods but check if this article helps https://blog.knoldus.com/unit-testing-void-methods-with-mockito-and-junit/

Answer (score 0):

you can test the `RefundReturnRequest refundReturnRequest` after the method executed.

```
@Test
void testSetRefundIdForPrepaid(){
   //build param
   RefundReturnRequest refundReturnRequest = new RefundReturnRequest();
   //executetd
   service.setRefundIdForPrepaid(refundReturnRequest);
   //test result
   assertThat(refundReturnRequest.getRefundRequest().getRefundId()).isEqualTo(xxx);
}
```

Comment: It is not working fot it

Answer (score 0):

You could make RefundReturnRequest a Spy and verify that the set was called. If you want to test it further you could pass on an Argument Captor and check that the random number is between a certain range. But this is type of method that I don't see much value in testing. If you wanna just write 2 test cases for the If logic just verify the set method has been called and another test where it hasn't been called.

So you'll need a Mock refundReturnRequest that returns a Spy RefundRequest after getRefundRequest is called. And verify the setter.

Answer (score -1):

```
@Test
void TestsetRefundIdForPrepaid(){
//test case
}
```

Comment: how to write test case